# Vuejs3 composable data is not present on mounted

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

i'm using vuejs3 with a simple test composable:

TEST COMPOSABLES
    Load post id:
    {{ i }}

```
<div v-if="error">
  <p>Oops! Error encountered: {{ error.message }}</p>
  <button @click="retry">Retry</button>
</div>
<div v-else-if="data">Data loaded: <pre>{{ data }}</pre></div>
<div v-else>Loading...</div>
```

```
<script setup>
import {ref, computed, onMounted} from 'vue'
import { useFetch } from '../composables/http.js'

const baseUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'
const id = ref('1')
const url = computed(() => baseUrl + id.value)

const { data, error, retry } = useFetch(url)

onMounted(async () => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
  console.log(data)
})
</script>
```

Composable file:

```
import { ref, watchEffect, toValue } from 'vue'

export function useFetch(url) {
    const data = ref(null)
    const error = ref(null)

    watchEffect(async () => {
        // reset state before fetching..
        data.value = null
        error.value = null

        // resolve the url value synchronously so it's tracked as a
        // dependency by watchEffect()
        const urlValue = toValue(url)

        try {
            // artificial delay / random error
            //await timeout()
            // unref() will return the ref value if it's a ref
            // otherwise the value will be returned as-is
            const res = await fetch(urlValue)
            data.value = await res.json()
        } catch (e) {
            error.value = e
        }
    })

    return { data, error }
}

// artificial delay
function timeout() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (Math.random() > 0.3) {
                resolve()
            } else {
                reject(new Error('Random Error'))
            }
        }, 300)
    })
}
```

Everything works fine but

console.log(JSON.stringify(data))   --> When access it on mounted this is null
console.log(data) --> console log start null then fill the data

The problem is that if i accessing a data.object inside the mounted i obtain an error "data is undefined" because the data.

If i go to lifecycle of vuejs3 i saw that the setup is the first loaded, and the mounted came where everything is mounted ...why i can't access the data?

Comment: Have you tried out `const { data, error, retry } = await useFetch(url)`?

Comment: the response of your api call is simply not there yet when the component is mounted. if for some reason you want to modify the data in the `onMounted` hook you need to make sure that the [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) returned by `fetch(url)` is fulfilled at this time before accessing the data.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Won't work as is, useFetch implementation doesn't return a promise-like, this is normal for composables

Answer (score 0):

The component is mounted on the next tick and can't and shouldn't be aware of asynchronous side effects inside `useFetch`. A composable like this one is supposed to be used with watchers:

```
const { data, error, retry } = useFetch(url)

watchEffect(() => {
  if (data.value)
    console.log(data.value)
})
```

Otherwise it needs to return a promise or promise-like, similarly to [Nuxt `useFetch`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch#usage), as suggested in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77535275/vuejs3-composable-data-is-not-present-on-mounted#comment136690579_77535275):

```
  const result = { data, error, then: () => resultPromise };
  let resolveResult;
  let resultPromise = new Promise(resolve => { resolveResult = resolve });
  watch([data, error], () => { resolveResult(result) });
  return result;
```

So it could be used with Suspense like:

```
const { data, error, retry } = await useFetch(url)
```

Unless `retry` is used, it's no better than using `await fetch(...)` in `setup`.

Another problem with the composable is that it uses `watchEffect` with `async`. The dependencies cannot be tracked when they are asynchronously accessed inside a callback, this is the limitation of JavaScript. Only the ones that are used before the first `await` will be taken into account.